# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi botón de Confirmar elimine uno de mis registros?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estoy usando jquery-confirm con laravel, la alerta si sale al presionar mi botón de eliminar, pero no sé como hacer que al presionar el botón de "confirmar" se elimine, de momento solo tengo configurado que salga la alerta de "You just confirmed".

Esta es mi sección de script:

```
$('button.Eliminar').confirm({
title:"¿Esta seguro de eliminar el registro?",
text:"Esta acción no se puede deshacer",
buttons:{
  Confirmar: function(button) {
    alert("You just confirmed.");
},
Cancelar:{},
}
});
```

Este es el codigo de mi botón de eliminar:

```
<form action="{{route('Formulario.Eliminar', $Formulario)}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          @method('delete')
          <button type="submit" name="Eliminar" id="Eliminar"class="Eliminar bg-red-200 opacity-85 hover:bg-red-400 text-xs text-gray-600 px-3 py-3 rounded-lg font-medium">Eliminar</button>  
        </form>
```

Comment: En lugar de la alerta redirige a la página que debe hacer el borrado o, mejor aún, ejecuta una petición AJAX a esa página.

Comment: coloca el codigo de la vista por favor, si es un form lo envias pero para poderte ayudar coloca el fragmento

Comment: @NicolasAldana Ya edité la publicación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar el formulario con ud id mediante jquery así

primero agregas el id como atributo al tag

```
<form action="{{route('Formulario.Eliminar', $Formulario)}}" method="POST" id="my-form">
          @csrf
          @method('delete')
          <button type="submit" name="Eliminar" id="Eliminar"class="Eliminar bg-red-200 opacity-85 hover:bg-red-400 text-xs text-gray-600 px-3 py-3 rounded-lg font-medium">Eliminar</button>  
        </form>
```

luego recuperas el id desde jquery con js vanilla y lo envias así

```
  $('button.Eliminar').confirm({
title:"¿Esta seguro de eliminar el registro?",
text:"Esta acción no se puede deshacer",
buttons:{
  Confirmar: function(button) {
   document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
},
Cancelar:{},
}
});
```

así debería funcionarte